# Connecting two 12V lights into a single power source

Tags: electrical, wiring, led

I am in the process of converting an old TV cabinet into a "barmoire" and have a question about lighting. I have two 12V [LED tape lights](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-8-ft-LED-Warm-White-Under-Cabinet-Light-LS2835-8F/306549382) and I would like them both to be switched using a single [door switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08JZCRN4W). The two tapes are not linkable; they each have their own separate AC adaptor. Is it OK to splice the wires from both tapes into a single AC adaptor, and if so, what kind of AC adaptor do I need? I'm guessing that wiring both tape lights into one of the stock adaptors could be problematic.  Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: Why can't you have a duplex receptacle that is switched to control 2 adapters?

Comment: What wattage rating are the two strips...?

Comment: I doubt you can run both tapes off just one of the pair of adapters that came with the tapes, since each adapter is likely to be sized to handle just one tape. But without sufficient details in your post, who knows? Please improve the question so that it includes all the technical details about your components, including the lengths of the tapes, the rated W/length of the tapes, the load capacities of the adapters, the exact configuration of the wires as they are now, including any plugs/outlets, and any other salient details.

Comment: The adapters are set up for a specific voltage / current. If you get an adapter or driver with the same voltage but 2x the wattage or current. Then you could put the lights in parallel and they would work. Switching the 1 adapter would then control both.

Answer (score 0):

We can't say because we don't know how *those linked* LED strips are manufactured, because they appear to be a sealed/matched unit.

However, if you went with standard/commodity LED strips, those are mostly 12 volts DC (some 24V available) and can be cut to length and fit.  Those, you simply total up how much power the LEDs (that you cut) are drawing, and provide a **UL-listed** 12 volt DC power supply to that length.  Switching 12V can be done with automotive-grade switches and does not need to meet the rigid NEC standards for 120V work.

Also, the switches you linked are "cheap Cheese junk".  Sadly, Amazon has opened their site to "the eBay crowd" and a huge amount of Amazon listings are the same garbage that you expect very little of from eBay.   Look for the "Ships by...Amazon Sold by... "   - that says you are for all practical purposes shopping on eBay.

Yes, it ships with Prime, but that's because Amazon has opened up their warehousing and shipment system to third parties *also*. In fact a lot of things you buy *actually on eBay* will get dropped off by an Amazon truck.